# Matplotlib: control tick placement for categorical axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are several posts how to adjust tick placement if the axis is based on a numerical variable. How do you do this for an axis based on different (categorical) variables?

Example: Some outcome variable is measured in several subjects at week 1, 2, 3, and finally week 6.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5, 4, 4, 3], [6, 4, 2, 3], [4, 4, 2, 1], 
                        [5, 4, 5, 2]], columns=['week1', 'week2', 'week3', 'week6'], 
                  index=['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4'])
```

The dataframe looks like this:
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biLqr.png)

Now I draw a line plot showing the changes of the variable over time:

```
plt.plot(df.transpose())
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVKuM.png)

How do I change the distance between ticks for week 3 and 6 to adequately reflect the timing of the measurements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the index of the transposed dataframe to numbers, create the plot (letting the numbers create the spacing), and then again assign the texts to the x ticks:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5, 4, 4, 3], [6, 4, 2, 3], [4, 4, 2, 1],
                        [5, 4, 5, 2]], columns=['week1', 'week2', 'week3', 'week6'],
                  index=['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4'])
df1 = df.transpose()
index_as_texts = df1.index
df1.index = [int(w[4:]) for w in index_as_texts]
plt.plot(df1)
plt.xticks(df1.index, index_as_texts)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot text ticks using numeric distances]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thx so much!